# Why does my dog push my crotch while I'm sleeping?

Tags: dogs, behavior, psychology

I have 6 dogs, the new dog will cover my crotch while sleeping... not a huge issue I guess but she uses her nose and sometimes pushes HARD. I heard they do that with food. Does she think my crotch is food? Is she trying some weird dominate thing?she will grab whatever is in reach and pile it up.

Answer (score 6):

Dogs "see" the world more with their nose than their eyes.  Not to get too graphic but the most odorous place on the human body is the genitals. Many dogs will sniff new people's crotches , much to the embarrassment of their owners. It's a dogs way of identifying and remembering who you are.  For whatever reason, some dogs do this much more than other dogs. If she/he is new, and you have a houseful of other dogs, she /he may be nervous and lays across your lap or pushes her nose into your crotch hard as a way to calm her/himself.  I know it sounds weird, but smelling their humans is very comforting to some dogs.  It's like they are saying "Ah !  There you are !"  Hope that helps. ZZ